# PHP MySQL Count Query Issue

Tags: php, mysql, count

*Disclaimer: I apologize in advance if there is a simple solution for this - I have looked at a lot of other examples similar to mine but cannot figure out how to solve this.

I am trying to count the number of customers in a sample database that use the same pickup location for their goods.

After connecting to the database, I have the following code:

```
$Table="Customer";

$custPerLocationCount = sprintf("SELECT COUNT('userName') FROM %s as total WHERE 'pickUpLocationID'='1'", $Table);

$result = mysqli_query($db, $custPerLocationCount);

$body .= "<h1>Customers Per Location</h1><table align='center'>
            <tr>
                <th>Location Name</th>
                <th>Number of Customers</th>
            </tr>";

    while ($recordArray = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) 
        {


             $locationName = "LOCATION1";
             $custCount = print_r($result['total']);

            $body .= "<tr>
                <td>".$locationName."</td>
                <td>".$custCount."</td>
            </tr>";
        };
        $body .="</table></br></br></br>";
```

Please ignore the table formatting.  I keep getting different errors as I change the code, but have not yet found how to solve this.

Comment: "SELECT COUNT('userName') as total FROM ..."

Comment: Are "userName" and "pickUpLocationID" column names? If they are, remove the quotes.

Comment: Show us some error messages please.By the way,you can't quote column names in SQL, you should use ` to wrap column names, like "SELECT COUNT( \`userName\` ) FROM %s as total WHERE \`pickUpLocationID\`='1'".

Comment: Did my answer worked? if so please select it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

In mysql, you use **`** to make the DB interprent the content as the column name, so you have to change your query to remove quotes from columns and you have to move the alias **total** to the end of the **SELECT** statement and before the **FROM**:

```
custPerLocationCount = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(`userName`) as total FROM %s WHERE `pickUpLocationID`='1'", $Table);
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  I did not realize there was a difference between ` and '.  However, I'm now getting the error " Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array" -- how would you display this if my `$custCount = print_r($result['total'])` is incorrect?  @Skatox

Comment: Oh, that's because `mysqli_query` returns a mysqli_result object, so you can't use it as an array. You can read more about it at:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php